# Simatic Microbox PC

Tags: plc, automation, siemens

I just started my research studies and part of it is based on an assembly line which uses a Microbox IPC427E for automation. However, I have never used a microbox before and only have some experience with Siemens PLC(200 and 300).

I tried to find if we can use Microbox for the same automation tasks as in a PLC or need to use a different PLC for the automation and feed the data to the Microbox with no luck. If anyone has previous experience with this system can you please tell me more information about this system.

Thank You,
Jay

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking on the wrong site. (1) This is a question and answer site, not a forum so "tell me more about" isn't a good fit. (2) The site is for electronics design questions and yours is a "use" question. (3) You haven't asked a specific answerable question. Please take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

Your microbox can have different licenses and programs installed. Without any it's just a normal PC. You would need a Runtime License and SIMATIC S7-1500 Software Controller CPU 1507S for programming it with TIA Portal, and/or SIMATIC WinCC Runtime Advanced V15 for HMI capabilities.

I guess, you can identify with product number on flash card.